# React Redux Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a redux function call in my react component, as below.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let gameId = this.props.match.params.gameId;

    this.props.fetchCurrentGameSession(gameId)
        .then(response => {
            if (response !== undefined) {
                if (!response.error) {
                    this.setState({
                        currentSession: {
                            loading: false,
                            loaded: true,
                            error: false,
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    this.setState({
                        currentSession: {
                            loading: false,
                            loaded: false,
                            error: true,
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

And the declaration of the functions:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchCurrentGameSession: (gameId) => dispatch(loadCurrentGameSession(gameId)),
    }
};


export default compose(
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    ),
    withStyles(styles, {
            withTheme: true
        }
    ))(LayoutGameView);
```

But sometimes, when the page loads, I get the error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Where would I add the function to change the state based on what the redux function returns so that I don't get this error?

Edit:

`action.js`:

```
export const FETCH_CURRENT_GAME_SESSION = '@@game/FETCH_CURRENT_GAME_SESSION';
export const FETCH_CURRENT_GAME_SESSION_SUCCESS = '@@game/FETCH_CURRENT_GAME_SESSION_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_CURRENT_GAME_SESSION_FAILURE = '@@game/FETCH_CURRENT_GAME_SESSION_FAILURE';
export const loadCurrentGameSession = (gameId) => ({
    [RSAA]: {
        endpoint: `/api/games/${gameId}/sessions/current`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: withAuth({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        types: [
            FETCH_CURRENT_GAME_SESSION, FETCH_CURRENT_GAME_SESSION_SUCCESS, FETCH_CURRENT_GAME_SESSION_FAILURE
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: make sure `loadCurrentGameSession` return a Promise. Only Promise can be use `.then`

Comment: @jdn How would I do that in this format?  I was searching and none of the examples had their actions formatted similar to mine, since I'm using RSAA middleware.  I added my `loadCurrentGameSession` to my post for viewing.

Comment: RSAA middleware package is 2 years old according to github. When choosing a dependency for your project avoid abandoned and unused packages.

Comment: use https://npms.io/ to search through npm to filter out abandoned packages.

Comment: @cclloyd Hope [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38818782/using-redux-api-middleware-to-process-image-jpeg-content) can help you. And as jstice4all sad, you should be avoid abandoned and unused packages.
If you can, try to use another middleware for your project to receive more support.